# How to send body with formData inside as a key fetch api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch

When I try to send image and a path to Api, it sends like `[object Object]`

```
export async function uploadImageToCDN(image: FormData, directory: string = 'dir'): Promise<any> {
const token = await authoriseInApi()

const headers = []
headers.push(['Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`])

const data: Content = new Content('multipart-file', {
    file: image,
    dir: directory
})
return post<any>('https://test-api.test.com/files/upload', data, headers)
```

}

This is how I collect data and send to Api:

```
const formData = new FormData()

    const imageBase64 = await getBase64(file)
    const imageUri = dataURIToBlob(imageBase64)

    formData.append('image', imageUri)

    const res = uploadImageToCDN(formData)
```

What is a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote xhr request and everything work fine.

Here is my request:

```
export async function uploadImageToCDN(formData: FormData): Promise<ICDNUploadResponse> {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const token = await getApiTokenByScope('scope')

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.open('post', '/api/test/files/upload')
    xhr.responseType = 'json'
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    xhr.onload = async () => {
        if (xhr.status === 401) {
            await refreshApiTokenByScope('scope')
                .then(() => {
                    uploadImageToCDN(formData)
                })
        }
        resolve(xhr.response)
    }
    xhr.onerror = () => {
        reject(xhr.response)
    }
    xhr.send(formData)
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify(data)` to send object parameter:

```
return post<any>('https://test-api.test.com/files/upload', JSON.stringify(data), headers)
```

Or if you want to use `fectch` try same thing:

```
//POST request with body equal on data in JSON format
fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
```

Comment: it will not work, cause of formData. FormData will be an empty object(

Comment: Did you use `fetch`?

Comment: yeap, i used fetch

Comment: @ChingizBatirbaev I suggest you to put a sample object like `{a:10}` and check to see it works or not. Based on official doc this `body: JSON.stringify(data),` must be work